# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value parsing json swift

Tags: swift

I try to parse json with swift using following:

```
   let apiPath = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1"

    func getDataWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: (_ jsonData: JSON?) -> Void) {


        let request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: apiPath)!)

 Alamofire.request(apiPath, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { (response) in
```

When my app running i got an error on line:

```
let request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: apiPath)!)
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value.

But i did pass correct string. Why is that error happen?

Comment: Remove this line from code.let request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: apiPath)!)

Comment: your apiPath is not a proper url string

Comment: @UsamaSadiq why? please try it and you will find json response.

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya i need url request. What you mean - remove?

Comment: can you post complete code? I mean with complete brackets. i just want test exactly

Comment: Issue is special character, and due to special character apiPath is not proper string, so URL is giving nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `URL` string contains special characters so what you need to do is encode your `URL` string before making `URL` object from it. There is two way to encode the `URL` string.

1. Using [`addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding)

   ```
   let apiPath = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1"
   if let encodeString = apiPath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed),
      let url = URL(string: encodeString) {
        print(url)
   }
   ```
2. Using [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents)

   ```
   var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast")!
   let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "München,DE"), URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: "b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1")]
   urlComponent.queryItems = queryItems
   print(urlComponent.url!)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Alamofire.request(“http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=München,DE&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1”, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters:nil , encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
           if response.result.isSuccess
           {
        //handle response
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You string content not correct symbol **"ü"** in this path **"q=München"**.

Replace it to correct symbol **"u"**.